# GIT: merge branches twice

Tags: git, merge, git-branch

I have a problem during merging two branches.
Consider the following git history structure:

```
      A---B---C feature
     /(1)    /(2)
D---E---F---G master
```

And I need to merge 'feature' branch in point (1) and (2).

(1) merged without any problems, but the second one shows

```
warning: refname 'feature' is ambiguous
Already up-to-date.
```

Could you help me, please? Thanks.

**Solved**. The problem was in tag with name 'feature' :)

Comment: Can you provide the complete git commands you execute?

Comment: git checkout master,
git merge feature

Comment: So, is *feature* a reserved word in *git*?

Comment: Yes, 'feature' branch name could cause problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to be on master to issue `git merge feature`.